# Using an AVL tree in java

Tags: java, avl-tree

I have the AVLNode and AVLTree classes, i have the methods to remove and insert nodes and i have a print method. I want to use these methods to create a AVL tree. On input i want to write  "Add x" and "Remove x". I wrote this but when i print nothing shows

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int i;
    BufferedReader scanner = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.readLine());
    String[] words = new String[n];
    AVLTree<Integer> t = new AVLTree<Integer>();

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String splitn = scanner.readLine();
        words[i] = (splitn.split(" ")[0]);
        int M = Integer.parseInt(splitn.split(" ")[1]);
        if (words[i] == "Add") {
            t.insert(M);
        }
        if (words[i] == "Remove") {
            t.remove(M);
        }

    }
    t.print();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
if (words[i] == "Add")
```

to:

```
if (words[i].equals("Add"))
```

And similarly for the `"Remove"` case. The `equals` method will compare the strings character by character, but the `==` operator just checks whether the two strings are the *same object in memory*. So, the reason nothing prints is that nothing is being added or removed in the first place!

Comment: `"Add".equals(words[i])` is even better (no risk of `NullPointerException`)